# MongoDB Aggreation Multiple Group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have millions of records like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568adba57faad8f22ff38a07"),
    "temperature" : 27,
    "elapsedTime" : 27,
    "stationId" : 28,
    "beaconId" : 238,
    "beaconClass" : 1,
    "batteryLevel" : 61
}
```

I want to group my records like this:

```
{"stationId":1, "beaconClass":1, total_time: summary_of_elapsedTime_in_station_for_this_beaconClass}
{"stationId":1, "beaconClass":2, total_time: summary_of_elapsedTime_in_station_for_this_beaconClass}
...
...
{"stationId":2, "beaconClass":1, total_time: summary_of_elapsedTime_in_station_for_this_beaconClass}
{"stationId":2, "beaconClass":2, total_time: summary_of_elapsedTime_in_station_for_this_beaconClass}
{"stationId":2, "beaconClass":3, total_time: summary_of_elapsedTime_in_station_for_this_beaconClass}
...
...
// so on
```

I can group by stationId or beaconId or class. But when I try to group by multiple column getting error.

How can I create aggregation query for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB group with multiple id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035627/mongodb-group-with-multiple-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For grouping on several fields you need to specify an aggregate key for the _id value. Take a look at the $group [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Try the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  
    $group: {
      _id: {stationId: "$stationId", beaconClass: "$beaconClass"}, 
      elapsedTime: {$sum: "$elapsedTime"}
    } 
  }
])
```

If you need to project the received fields to another schema you can take advantage of [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator in the aggregation:

```
{
    $project: { _id: 0, stationId: "$_id.stationId", beaconClass: "$_id.beaconClass", elapsedTime: 1 } 
}
```

Comment: It works! I can't believe how is that simple. Thank you.

Comment: And please can you give me some explanation why didn't we use multiple `$group` key? How can it handle so easy?

Comment: Don't start your answer with *Try the following query*  Instead try to explain what your query is doing and why it works. Also you don't need the `$project` stage here because it will cause a drop of performance.